# TinyMCE troubles on paste

Tags: tinymce

I'm having troubles configuring the editor, I'm tryng to delete breaks.
When I paste the text from other apps (word, wordpad...). it generates `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
where there's a break, but the space between every paragraph is too large (because the `p` element default margin i think)
So i tried to not generate paragraph on pase using

```
paste_create_paragraphs: false,
paste_create_linebreaks: false,
```

but it still generate the `<p>` tag.
Then I tryed with `paste_postprocess` to force deletion of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` **but nothing is working**.

This is my full TinyMCE init

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 200,
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold underline italic strikethrough | backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table ',
    toolbar2: 'numlist bullist | outdent indent | removeformat | subscript superscript | link unlink',
    fontsize_formats: '7px 8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 17px 18px 19px 20px 21px 22px 23px 24px 25px 26px 27px 28px 29px 30px',
    image_advtab: true,
    block_formats: 'Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3;Header 4=h4;Header 5=h5;Header 6=h6;',
    image_class_list: [
      { title: 'Immagine Responsive', value: 'img-responsive img-fluid' },
      //{ title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox' },
    ],
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
    paste_create_paragraphs: false,
    paste_create_linebreaks: false,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_postprocess: function (pl, o) {
        // remove &nbsp
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, "");
        // just a try
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding `paste` in the `plugins` block

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 200,
    theme: 'modern',
    // ADDED "paste" plugin
    plugins: 'paste  print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold underline italic strikethrough | backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table ',
    toolbar2: 'numlist bullist | outdent indent | removeformat | subscript superscript | link unlink',
    fontsize_formats: '7px 8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 17px 18px 19px 20px 21px 22px 23px 24px 25px 26px 27px 28px 29px 30px',
    image_advtab: true,
    block_formats: 'Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3;Header 4=h4;Header 5=h5;Header 6=h6;',
    image_class_list: [
      { title: 'Immagine Responsive', value: 'img-responsive img-fluid' },
      //{ title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox' },
    ],
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
    paste_create_paragraphs: false,
    paste_create_linebreaks: false,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_postprocess: function (pl, o) {
        // remove &nbsp
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, "");
        // just a try
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "");
      }
});
```